# std::popcount identifier not found in MSVC 16.6.0

Tags: c++, c++20, visual-c++-2019

Am I doing something wrong or is Microsoft's support of `std::popcount` broken in version 16.6.0 of Visual Studio?

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 16.6.0, with C++ Language Standard set to *Preview - Features from the Latest C++ Working Draft (std:c++latest)* and trying to compile [the popcount sample code from cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount):

```
#include <bit>
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdint>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for (std::uint8_t i : { 0, 0b11111111, 0b00011101 }) {
        std::cout << "popcount(0b" << std::bitset<8>(i) << ") = "
            << std::popcount(i) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Even though cppreference states that bit operations ([P0553R4](https://wg21.link/P0553R4)) [have been supported since version 16.5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) and MSVC 16.6 defines the feature macro `__cpp_lib_bitops`, the above code gives the following errors:

```
Error   C3861   'popcount': identifier not found    ConsoleApplication3 C:\Users\rsjaf\source\repos\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3.cpp 22  
Message     see declaration of 'std'    ConsoleApplication3 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\iostream    19  
Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "popcount"    ConsoleApplication3 C:\Users\rsjaf\source\repos\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3.cpp 22  
Error   C2039   'popcount': is not a member of 'std'    ConsoleApplication3 C:\Users\rsjaf\source\repos\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3.cpp 22
```

When I look in the `bit` header, I do see a template for `popcount`, but it seems to be disabled for my application.

Comment: It's funny, Intellisense knows about the function and F12 jumps to the implementation but the compiler emits a "not a member of std" error. You might want to report a problem at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/

Comment: I reported it. We'll see. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1047273/popcount-identifier-not-found-in-msvc-1660.html

Comment: Looking at `yvals_core.h`, `__cpp_lib_bitops` is defined only for Clang. I can't say why, but `// a future MSVC update will embed CPU feature detection into <bit> intrinsics` - maybe they're waiting until then?

Comment: @chris I’m getting a valid value for the macro, even though compilation fails.

Comment: It could be that what you see is Intellisense finding the definition that doesn't apply to your configuration (and you can navigate to the definition to check). I'm having trouble recalliing how that sort of Intellisense support has changed over the years; I looked at the implementation available on Github rather than a local one. Now that I say that, I found my local one and it includes EDG as well as Clang. I imagine that impacts Intellisense because VS's Intellisense engine is EDG.

Answer (score 4):

With current MSVC `std::popcount` is available under `/std:c++20` and `/std:c++latest`.

---

As @chris pointed out, the feature was not implemented yet, since runtime CPU feature detection is not yet implemented.

The PR to finalize and enable it is in work in progress state:
https://github.com/microsoft/STL/pull/795

Defining `__cpp_lib_bitops` (for intellisense) and `__cpp_lib_int_pow2` (generally) before implementing them was a bug. It was fixed by https://github.com/microsoft/STL/pull/695 , but the fix may be still not available for latest version due to the latency of changes integration.